# Retagged questions shouldn't move to the top of the active list

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, active

**My feature request:** questions that have only been retagged (but not otherwise edited) should not be moved to the top of the *active questions* list.

Retagging questions (without making any further edit) currently moves them to the top of the [active questions list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=active).  It makes sense for normal [edits to appear at the top of the active questions list](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1234/should-the-edit-feature-reset-the-questions-scroll/1238) because they edit the actual content of the question. Moving *content edits* to the top of the list helps support peer moderation.

However, moving *retagged* questions to the top of the list is problematic for two reasons.

1. It **buries questions** that have had their actual content changed, including posts that are completely new.  If used properly, tags should only help to find questions, not to change their meaning, so there's no need to place them in a list where people are expected to respond to them.
2. It enables users to **get a couple of free votes** just by retagging one of their questions or a question for which they have a popular answer. This can clog up the list with "activity" that didn't actually change any of the question's meaning.

Comment: Would the people who are downvoting please leave comments explaining why?  If you don't like my suggestion, I'd be interested to hear your explanation.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/whats-meta)

Answer (score 10):

I don't like this idea for a couple of reasons:

1. Not bumping questions means that there's no review that the change was correct.
2. If the question is now correctly tagged and wasn't before the OP has missed out on all attention to their question. It's not being bumped in the same filters as the tags are now different.

Don't forget that if a user edits their own questions more than 10 times it becomes community wiki and the OP doesn't get any more reputation for their question.

Comment: Interesting points.  I've just posted a [follow-up question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183232/newest-answers-list) that may be an alternative way around the clutter caused by retags.